# How can I add android emulator as favourites in launcher bar ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: unity, launcher, android, android-emulator

I want to add android emulator to the desktop launcher bar in Ubuntu 19.04. When I right click on the started(from the android studio -> tools -> AVD manager) emulator icon, it doesn't show a favorites option as some other applications to pin it to the desktop launcher bar. [emulator icon with pressed right click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hghqn.png)

Comment: `The emulator is started through android studio which is another application.` - you should add that to your question. Possibly with images.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment because I don't have enough reputation. Is the Android Emulator only the app that you can't add to favorites?

You can try one of these:

Restart your laptop.
Click "All Applications" and drag an app to the toolbar.

Or there could be a bug that doesn't let you favorite a specific app. Check out this link:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=738672#c1

Comment: Actually this answer is not valid for the question. The emulator is started through android studio which is another application.

Answer (score 0):

You say in comment `The emulator is started through android studio which is another application.`

So, it might not even be a separate application. (I cannot test myself.) But if it were a separate application, you would be able to find its launcher in `usr/share/applications`, then drag & drop that on your bar.

If it is not a separate application, you could [create a specific launcher](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=create%20a%20desktop%20file) for the command that starts it and add that launcher to the bar.

Now, **supposing your program opens a window**, you could find the command that starts it with `xwininfo`.

- start the emulator
- start a terminal; run `xwininfo`; the mouse cursor changes to a cross
- click on the emulator window; note the  Window id: NUMBER that appears in terminal
- run in terminal `xprop -id XXXX | grep PID`, where XXXX is that NUMBER; note the PID number
- run `ps aux | grep XXXX`, where the XXXX is the PID number above

You will get a line starting with that PID and ending with the command you are looking for. Note that command, add it in the `Exec` line of a launcher `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications`, drop that on the bar.